# Import-module doesn't run more than once

Tags: powershell, import-module

I have a script that should copy over another script and run the module, however when I try to run this more than once, it just ends, without warning, no out-put/errors.

I have been working importing modules to help my script run better and to also simplify use.

```
$Script:Es = $PSScriptRoot + "\" + "Main Script.psm1"
$Script:Ma32 = "C:\Temp\Scripts2"
$Script:E2 = "\Main Script.psm1"
$Script:E3 = $Ma32 + $E2

Function Get-Check {
    if ( -Not (Test-Path -Path $Ma32 ) ) {
        New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $Ma32 |out-null
    }
}

Function Get-Run {
    copy-item $Es $Ma32
    Import-Module $E3 
}

Function St {
    Get-Check
    Get-Run
}

St
```

Comment: You have added too many contents. Just give the function from which you are trying to import the module and the logic. Read [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As requested I have amended the code, only to show the script that runs only once.

Comment: So your script is not having any error although the logic can be optimized further. When you are calling the script for the first time, it is importing the module in the terminal. If you rerun,it is evident that it will not do anything because already the module being imported. To validate that why dont you get the module first followed by the functions/commands inside your custom module by `Get-Module -ListAvailable *` and `Get-Command -Module yourmodulename`

Comment: I think the second part was important to understand the problem. The problem is you secondpart is not a module but a script. See `help about_modules`. Modules are ment to contain functions and the like to provide them in your session. Not to execute actions and be executed over and over. They are ment to be only imported once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers, using `-force` resolves the issue.

```
Import-Module $E3 -force
```